# No splash screens, just a black screen until the Windows login screen appears

Tags: windows, bios

I just got a new SSD for my Dell XPS 8920 and Windows 10 has been installed on it. Windows seems to be working fine.

However, I noticed a strange new behavior from the computer which is that the Dell splash screen no longer appears, and nor does the option to press F2/F12 appear on the screen, and nor does a Windows splash screen appear. Instead the screen just stays black until the Windows login screen appears. Then Windows seems to run as normal.

I believe that if I press F2 during start up the goes into BIOS, because if I press F2 then Windows startup is interrupted and the computer goes into BIOS. But I can only see a black screen, so I can't do anything in BIOS.

Things that have been tried already to fix this problem:

1. Turning off "Fast startup".
2. Flashing the latest BIOS.
3. Following [this advice](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln143038/access-uefi-bios-system-setup-from-windows-on-your-dell-system?lang=en) to try to get into BIOS from Windows.
4. Turning the option for Hibernation off.

In all cases I get a black screen unless I proceed onto the Windows login screen.

Comment: When in windows disable hibernation, the restart, is it fixed now? Run this command in an elevated command prompt to disable hibernation: Powercfg -H off

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: When in windows hold down the shift key when you click Restart.

Comment: Using that I can (I think) get into BIOS, but I can't see anything - the screen remains black. It's the same if I press F2 as the computer is booting.

Comment: Did you have W10 on the old drive? Was it a clean W10 install on the new drive?

Comment: Yes, clean W10 install on the new drive. I also had W10 on the old drive.

Comment: Bang head here>>> X